# Problem in installing Ubuntu 20.10 from live USB

Tags: partitioning, uefi, live-usb, mbr, 20.10

I am trying to do a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.10 on my Dell Inspiron 14z-N411z. I downloaded the official ISO and flashed it onto a sandisk USB using the built in "Startup Disk Creator". When I then try to boot using the USB I get the error `No Operating System Found!`. However it did work on a my desktop?! I tried using a different USB only to get the same error. Then I tried using the Ubuntu 20.04 LTS ISO, which worked!

It seems that the 20.10 ISO when flashed has GPT partitioning while 20.04 had MBR partitioning, which I suspect to be the root of the problem. It seems some windows softwares like rufus allow you to select the type of partitioning but the startup disk creators on Ubuntu don't offer the same.

Could anyone guide on how to solve this?

Some extra information:
I have installed Ubuntu several times before this so I am pretty sure I am doing it correctly. The BIOS of my laptop doesn't have any options related to UEFI/Legacy (It's pretty old), however my desktop does. And I currently don't have access to any windows device.

Comment: It's been GPT for a while with Ubuntu, definitely for 20.04. I'd try another way of writing the ISO, for example dd.

Comment: @mikewhatever Yeah I've tried using dd, it gives the same error. 20.04 used MBP, I've checked.

Comment: I have tried Ubuntu 20.10 on my BIOS only, (pre-UEFI), computer with USB's made using Rufus, Etcher-Windows, Etcher-Linux, Gnome-Disks, Startup Disk Creator, Unetbootin and mkusb. They all worked using the latest ISO. I have heard that some computers boot 20.10 better than others. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-cdimage/+bug/1886148

Comment: Unetbootin, Rufus and mkusb will all make you a bootable USB with a msdos/mbr partition table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### MBR, (MSDOS) Bootable Live/Persistent USB Drive

- Cloning a Live Ubuntu 20.04 and later ISO using Etcher, Gnome-Disks, Startup Disk Creator, dd, etc, will produce a Live USB with a GPT partition table.

**Some computers may prefer a Live USB with a MBR partition table.**

- UNetbootin 681 will make a MBR Live or Persistent USB drive, just ensure that the USB has a MBR partition table before proceeding with USB creation. https://unetbootin.github.io/
- Rufus Version 3.12 (2020.10.14) will make a MBR Live or Persistent USB drive, Select `MBR` for `Partition scheme`. https://rufus.ie/
- Mkusb version 12.6.4 will make a MBR Live/Persistent USB drive. At `persistent live drive settings`, Select `msdos`. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1958073&page=103&p=13993880#post13993880